# Understanding Angular layout while using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, layout, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code in one of my angular html files. I am trying to get div elements adjacent to each other with ng-repeat in a carousel.

Here is what I did so far.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

            <div class="item active" layout="row">
                <div class="message" flex=33
                    ng-repeat="message in messages.images " layout-align="start end"
                     ng-if="$index > 0 && $index < 3">
                    <span class="video-message-name">{{message.text}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" layout="row">
                <div class="message" flex=33
                    ng-repeat="message in messages.images " layout-align="start end"
                     ng-if="$index > 2 && $index < 6">
                    <span class="video-message-name">{{message.text}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item" layout="row">
                <div class="message" flex=33
                    ng-repeat="message in messages.images " layout-align="start end"
                    ng-if="$index > 6 && $index < 9">
                    <span class="video-message-name">{{message.text}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

The issue here is I am expecting the divs to look as this

```
message 1    message 2    message 3
```

But it is coming like

```
message 1

message 2

message 3
```

Can someone help me understanding layouts in this context.

Comment: This might be css issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about Angular this is about CSS you can try:

```
.item{
    width: 100%
}    
.message{

    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%
 }
```

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Whc/101/)**

Answer (score 0):

There is an angular solution to this as well. Just need to move those class 'message' div's under a single class 'item' div. The layout=row in the 'item' div assigns the left to right layout. And if you add flex the item div it will fill the width of the page, then the flex="33" can be removed from the children elements, as simple flex will assign them all the same width.

0 && $index 
            {{message.text}}
        
         2 && $index 
            {{message.text}}
        
         6 && $index 
            {{message.text}}